For loop over split data frames, applying function, and saving output
I'm splitting a data frame into three separate data frames and then applying a function to each of those separate data frames. How can I do this with a for loop (saving more than just the last dataset)? And how can I do this with lapply? (When I do it here, I get the error: Error in UseMethod("filter") :  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"  (Mt cars mpg class is numeric.)
When I'm doing a similar thing in my use-case (many different tidy verse functions, etc.), I'm getting the error Error in `select()`: ! `select()` doesn't handle lists. (I do see this answer: R: `select()` doesn't handle lists it seems like a pretty common thing to implement larger functions with select statements in lapply.
MRE below.
dfs_cars = split(mtcars, ~cyl)

filter_mpg <- function(dat, mpg_greater){
  dat%>%
    filter(mpg > mpg_greater)
}

for (i in dfs_cars){
  ns = i%>%filter_mpg(21)
}

lapply(dfs_cars, filter_mpg(21))


To use a for loop, you should prepare an object to hold the result of each iteration of the loop. I made the OutList list for this. I then iterate over an index and increment the position in both dfs_cars and OutList.
To use lapply, the second argument should be the bare function name, not filter_mpg(21), and the second argument of the function can be supplied separately in the ... argument of lapply.
library(tidyverse)
dfs_cars = split(mtcars, ~cyl)

OutList <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(dfs_cars))

filter_mpg <- function(dat, mpg_greater){
  dat%>%
    filter(mpg > mpg_greater)
}

for (i in seq_along(dfs_cars)){
  OutList[[i]] = dfs_cars[[i]] %>% filter_mpg(21)
}
OutList
#> [[1]]
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)


OutList2 <- lapply(dfs_cars, filter_mpg, mpg_greater = 21)
OutList2
#> $`4`
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> 
#> $`6`
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 
#> $`8`
#>  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Created on 2024-10-21 with reprex v2.1.1

I am aware you asked specifically for solutions using a for loop and lapply(), resp., but since you are using tidyverse anyway, have you considered purrr::map()? You do not have to create an additional object to store the output for each group.
If you wanted to combine everything afterwards, just use purrr::list_rbind()
library(tidyverse)

dfs_cars = split(mtcars, ~cyl)

filter_mpg <- function(dat, mpg_greater){
  dat %>%
    filter(mpg > mpg_greater)
}

dfs_cars %>%
  map(~filter_mpg(.x, 21))
#> $`4`
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> 
#> $`6`
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 
#> $`8`
#>  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Created on 2024-10-22 with reprex v2.1.1
